# fetch twitter content using simpleXmlElement in php fails

Tags: php, sxml

I had googled a code to fetch a public twitter content, it work fine when on my localhost but when I put it online on a hosted server, it does not seem to respond at all! Code is as below.

For example `url ='https://twitter.com/#!/NatureMagazine'`

```php
if($entered['domain']=='twitter.com')
{
    $baseName = basename($url);
    // HINT Code works fine up to here but after this statement, nothing comes out

    $sXML = new SimpleXMLElement('http://twitter.com/users/show.xml?screen_name='.$baseName, NULL, TRUE);

    // TRUE specifies that data is a path or URL to an XML document instead of string data.
    $screen_name                = $sXML->screen_name;
    $location                   = $sXML->location;
    $description                = $sXML->description;
}
```

Note: The same code works as expected on my local system.

Comment: Check the `phpinfo()` page for extensions that were compiled into your hosted PHP. Maybe `simplexml` was not added as an extension.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: Before PHP 5.1.2, --enable-simplexml is required to enable this
>   extension.

Do a `phpinfo()` to check if libxml extension is ON in your server environment.

Share more info about that exactly is the problem. Because from code, you have not placed status checkers to help you debug along the way.

I hope the `exit();` is not exactly been uploaded to the server.

Comment: Ok, I'll check further. You are right "exit()" was only for my testing

Comment: I Checked the information and found this
"libXML support active
libXML Compiled Version 2.7.8
libXML Loaded Version 20708
libXML streams enabled"